# How to call an action on backspace in UItextView, while encountering a substring between character "@" and " " (space)

Tags: ios, string, swift, logic, uitextview

**Motive:** I have UItextview and user can enter comments in it, like **Instagram** app.  In this textview user can mention his follower's name starting with character "@", similar to Twitter or Instagram.

For example : I want to type `"Hi, @john, you know @ankush ?"` so after typing `"Hi, "` when I press `"@"` app will show list of all followers. And as I will type further `@j` list will be filtered and show all followers, whose name starts with character `"j"` and so on

I have achieved it successfully.

**The problem**

Lets say I have written `Hi, @john, you` now I start pressing backspace so I when text become "Hi, @john" I want to show the list of followers whose name contain `"john"`. How can I achieve this. How system will know that its time to show the list again while pressing back space. what would be the logic in code?

I am completely new in Swift and learning. I have googled but no use. Someone please help.

Comment: You could keep an array of all the indices within the text that would trigger the list of followers. An entry would be added to the array for every time you type space after the initial '@'.

Comment: yeah you are right. But how would I know to its time to show list while pressing back space ?

Comment: Checking for backspace wouldn't be necessary. As long as your cursor is on an index included in the array, show list of followers.